# Gspread keep alive after update google auth2

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

There are several examples for 'keep the connection with google spreadsheet alive' 
But all I found are based on the 'old' Google Sign-In system which isn't work anymore since april 2015

What is the proper methode to keep the connection with googlespreadsheet alive using OAuth 2.0

I've Tried this

```
import gspread

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

headers = gspread.httpsession.HTTPSession(headers={'Connection':'Keep-Alive'}) #Allows a persistant connection.
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Apps Script Execution API.json', scope)
    c = gspread.authorize(auth=credentials,http_session=headers)
```

result:
c = gspread.authorize(auth=credentials,http_session=headers)
TypeError: authorize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late answer to your question is:

```
import gspread
from gspread.httpsession import HTTPSession

from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
key_name = 'something.json'
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(key_name, scope)

#gc = gspread.authorize(credentials) doesn't have a http_session kwarg
http_session = HTTPSession(headers={'Connection':'Keep-Alive'})
gc = gspread.Client(credentials, http_session)
gc.login()
ss = gc.open("Sachibondu-MasonryVaults")
```